# Is it bad practice to user a service to maintain state between controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I have a number of sibling controllers and to the side of the screen I have some filters and options that generally can apply to any controller. My problem is that I want to preserve the state of the options for use from any of the controllers.

The way I understand this should be done from reading is to create a service which I can then inject into my controller and use the exposed `getter/setter` methods to access values.

However, from the AngularJS docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) the last paragraph, which advises against using `$rootScope` for this purpose, also notes `Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data.`

Is it bad practice to use a service as a singleton for passing data between controllers? What are the complications and tradeoffs and what are alternative approaches?

Comment: The question is too broad and depends on your particular case. The paragraph was taken out of context, the point is that a service should be a model (as in MVC) and also have methods to manipulate its data, not to just give it away to controllers that have these methods (so-called fat controllers).

Comment: To backup what @estus says, by giving your service a `getter/setter` you have gone beyond creating a service to just store and return bits of data. Presumably your `getter/setter` have more logic in them (for example, handling the situation where a property value is set to `null`). If you are truly concerned about using a service for the purpose of sharing state then use a value instead. A value is just way of sharing an object reference among multiple controllers.

Comment: That makes sense, I figured that the `getter/setter` paradigm is what they were after here.